# How to replace every possible subset of a string in PostgeSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-programming

I am looking for a block of code in PostgreSQL to replace every possible subset of a string from a list,I have a list of synonyms and want to replace every synonyms in a string example if I have a string named "ABS PVT LTD" and I have synonyms for PVT as PRIVATE and LTD as LIMITED and viceversa then I want my output to be an array of all possible combination i.e.

ABS PVT LTD , ABS PVT LIMITED , ABS PRIVATE LTD , ABS PRIVATE LIMITED

for my current approach I am getting the output but not all possible combiation i.e.
ABS PVT LIMITED , ABS PRIVATE LIMITED

I have attached my current code

```
    coalesce(array_agg(regexp_replace(stringtransformation('ABS PVT LTD', true),concat('\y',keyword,'\y'), syno)),ARRAY[]::text[])
from
    synonyms s
where
    keyword in (
    select
        unnest(
   string_to_array(stringtransformation('ABS PVT LTD', true), ' ')
)
);
```

These are my synonyms

[image]

Comment: can you share sample input tables, you current output and the desired corresponding output?

Comment: Additionally update your question to post your synonyms as formatted text not as an image.  See [here](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) for how to easily create formatted text, or even better create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14).

Comment: LIMITED as a synonym for LTD, and LTD as a synonym for LIMITED, which is a loop. Please explain. Also, as per the [*How to ask* guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a simpler way, but I would use a combination of unions, joins, and recursion.

This CTE simulates a synonym table with only one side of each pairing:

```
with recursive synonyms_unidirectional (keyword, synonym) as (
  values ('PVT', 'PRIVATE'),
         ('LTD', 'LIMITED')
),
```

Union it to itself to get the reverse synonyms:

```
synonyms as (
  select keyword, synonym from synonyms_unidirectional
  union 
  select synonym, keyword from synonyms_unidirectional
),
```

This simulates a table to hold your company names:

```
company (id, company_name) as (
  values (1, 'ABS PVT LTD')
),
```

Split the names into rows, and keep track of how many words are in each company name:

```
words as (
select c.id, w.*, max(w.n) over (partition by id) as nwords
  from company c
       cross join lateral 
         regexp_split_to_table(c.company_name, '\s+') with ordinality as w(word, n)
),
```

Preserve each original word and union that with a join to the bidirectional synonyms table (CTE):

```
words_and_synonyms as (
  select id, n, word as synonym, nwords
    from words
   union 
  select w.id, w.n, s.synonym, nwords
    from words w
         join synonyms s on s.keyword = w.word
)
```

Use recursion to rebuild each possible combination of keywords and synonyms:

```
, rejoin as (
  select id, n, array[synonym] as company_name, nwords
    from words_and_synonyms 
   where n = 1
  union all
  select p.id, c.n, p.company_name||c.synonym, p.nwords
    from rejoin p
         join words_and_synonyms c 
           on c.id = p.id
          and c.n = p.n + 1
)
```

Reconstruct the string from the array, and keep only the rows that have the right number of words:

```
select id, array_to_string(company_name, ' ') as company_name 
  from rejoin
 where n = nwords;
```

The result:

```
┌────┬─────────────────────┐
│ id │    company_name     │
├────┼─────────────────────┤
│  1 │ ABS PRIVATE LTD     │
│  1 │ ABS PVT LTD         │
│  1 │ ABS PRIVATE LIMITED │
│  1 │ ABS PVT LIMITED     │
└────┴─────────────────────┘
(4 rows)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b1c6936e2eedf10d557758e29cf15d12)*